# The file could not be opened when request made using `NSURL`

Tags: swift2

I make a http request for the below URL :

I got below err msg:

> Optional (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain code = 256)
>   The file image could not be opened.

[File URL](http://portal-webserver-xxx-1025638813.ap-southeast-1.xxx.amazonaws.com/smart/images/xxx.html)

**code**

```
let myURLString ="http://portal-webserver-xxx-1025638813.ap-southeast-1.xxx.amazonaws.com/smart/images/xxx.html "

let myURL = NSURL(string:myURLString)

let myHTML :NSString?

myHMTL = NSString(contentsOfURL:myURL!,encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

I want to get the HTML file from the url. The code is using older swift version, what I need to use. please help.
Thanks.

Comment: is given URL accessible from browser, especially in Safari?

Comment: You're telling us about an image issue but the code you're showing is only about getting the HTML. Please include the relevant code.

Comment: Yes, I used FireFox.

Comment: The image file is inside the HTML which I need to parse later.

Comment: And how are we supposed to help you parse the HTML if we can't see it?! Please include an example. :) Also please include what you tried, maybe we can help improve your code.

Comment: My problem is that I cannot even get the HTML code from the URL . I encountered the error msg before getting the HTML string. So I dont know what is the problem and what cause the problem. Is the problem in contentsOfURL ? Is there any other way instead of NSURL?

Comment: That URL has a space at the end...

Comment: The space has taken out. it is the same error again. The host is Amazon webservice :amazonaws, is it the host blocking access to the actual server ?  In this case, I need to use WebView to display the HTML??

Comment: @Eric D : I used UIWebView to display the image but the result is not the same if I paste this URL in Browser. U can try this :http://portal-webserver-elb-1025638813.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/trafficsmart/images/xxxx.html     Replace xxxx with 4703  Please advise how to overcome this problem. Thanks

Comment: @Eric: Do you have any solution to my problem? Thanks

Comment: This page returns HTML. The image is just an HTML link. If you reallt don't have an API to get this image, you can parse the HTML and get the link. You can use libraries like "Fuzi" for example.

Comment: I tried so many time. It seems WebBrowser can display the image. But in Xcode ,I keeping getting this error : Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain code=256 Even I had added AppTransport Security Settings/ allow ArbitraryLoads in Info.Plist. In Browser I can see the Image  img src=/trafficsmart/images/xxxxxxx.jpg But What is the proper URL Address for this img ? Can u show me your code that works. Thanks in advance.